# react-admin - Stop List's Filters from submitting "onChange"

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to have a List's filters not submit automatically on every field's change? I'm trying to implement a reporting resource and it would be ideal to have the user set the filters they want and then submit the form, to have the report generated, as they tend to be heavy on the DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

React-admin's `<Filter>` component does not submit after every field change, because it uses a debouncing function to submit only once the user has stopped typing.

That being said, if you don't want the filter form to auto-submit, but prefer a filter form with an explicit submit button, you'll have to build a custom `<Filter>` component yourself - react-admin doesn't provide such a component.

Here is an example custom filter form:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import { Box, Button, InputAdornment } from '@material-ui/core';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { TextInput, NullableBooleanInput, useListContext } from 'react-admin';

const PostFilterForm = () => {
  const {
    displayedFilters,
    filterValues,
    setFilters,
    hideFilter
  } = useListContext();

  if (!displayedFilters.main) return null;

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    if (Object.keys(values).length > 0) {
      setFilters(values);
    } else {
      hideFilter("main");
    }
  };

  const resetFilter = () => {
    setFilters({}, []);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} initialValues={filterValues}>
        {({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Box display="flex" alignItems="flex-end" mb={1}>
              <Box component="span" mr={2}>
                {/* Full-text search filter. We don't use <SearchFilter> to force a large form input */}
                <TextInput
                  resettable
                  helperText={false}
                  source="q"
                  label="Search"
                  InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment>
                        <SearchIcon color="disabled" />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    )
                  }}
                />
              </Box>
              <Box component="span" mr={2}>
                {/* Commentable filter */}
                <NullableBooleanInput helperText={false} source="commentable" />
              </Box>
              <Box component="span" mr={2} mb={1.5}>
                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit">
                  Filter
                </Button>
              </Box>
              <Box component="span" mb={1.5}>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={resetFilter}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is documented at: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#building-a-custom-filter

Edit 2021-11-10: Added example and link to documentation

Comment: I've been following `React-admin` filter questions relate to filter-when-submit. You are repeating that you need to implement a custom `<Filter>`, perhaps at least give an example of how to do it. That will definitely help the community.

Comment: I completed the answer with an example and a link to the documentation for that.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I also worked on this item and went into the path of building a new `SubmitFilter` component, to remove `<FormSpy ... ` inside `FilterForm`. It's sort of working and I was about to publish the answer here after I clean up the code. I will try your suggestion as well.